# Neyman Pearson Lemma -- Optimizing for Detecting the Null Hypothesis

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, parameter-estimation

So for my Neyman-Pearson test, I have already calculated the sufficient statistic $T$. It is distributed as following:

$$ T_{|H_{0}} = \text{Rayleigh}(\sigma)$$
$$ T_{|H_{1}} = \text{Rice}(A, \sigma)$$

It is clear how to design the detector to detect $H_{1}$. In other words, we want to find the threshold $\gamma$ such that we minimize the probability of false alarm:

$$ P_{FA|H_{1}} = Pr\left( T \geq \gamma | H_{0}  \right)$$

This means our detection probability is:

$$ P_{D|H_{1}} = Pr\left( T \geq \gamma | H_{1}  \right)$$

However, I want to find $\gamma$ such that I detect $H_{0}$ with a minimal $P_{FA}$. Would it just be:

$$ P_{FA|H_{0}} = Pr\left( T \geq \gamma | H_{1}  \right)$$
$$ P_{D|H_{0}} = Pr\left( T \geq \gamma | H_{0}  \right)$$

In other words, would I just switch the hypotheses? Or would it be:

$$ P_{FA|H_{0}} = Pr\left( T \leq \gamma | H_{1}  \right)$$
$$ P_{D|H_{0}} = Pr\left( T \leq \gamma | H_{0}  \right)$$

---

Edit:

I am using $P_{FA|H_{j}}$ to denote the probability of false alarm, given that I want to detect hypothesis $H_{j}$. Similary, $P_{D}$ stands for the probability of detection.

$Pr\left( T \leq \gamma | H_{j}  \right)$ means simply the probability that the test statistic $T$ is less than or equal to $\gamma$ given $H_{j}$ is true.

I want to know what the forms of $P_{FA|H_{0}}$ and $P_{D|H_{0}}$ should be. Ie how should I determine the false alarm and detection probability given that I want to detect $H_{0}$? Also, can I choose $\gamma$ to minimize the probability of false alarm given that I want to detect $H_{0}$?

Comment: I think it would be good to normalize terminology. FA = false alarm? how come you have P_{FA|H0} in the left hand side, and Pr(T>gamma|H1) in the right hand side?

Comment: @DanielS. Please see my edits. I hope that helps. Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with this sort of hypothesis test.  I thought that to determine probability of false alarm we would not need H1.  That FA was completely determined given H0. So, I'm still puzzled by the fact that to compute FA you use H1

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis test I was looking for was to detect a true negative while minimizing the probability of false negatives.

In other words, I want to compute:

$$ P_{D|H_{0}} = P_{TN} = P\left( T \leq \gamma | H_{0} \right)  $$

where I choose gamma to minimize:

$$ P_{FN} = P\left( T \leq \gamma | H_{1} \right)  $$

This is essentially the reverse hypothesis test, which is what I was going for. This allows me to optimally detect when the null hypothesis is true.